# Setting a pointer to null crashes my C++ program

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a constructor, that receives a character pointer.  If it is empty, I need to set its member variable to NULL, however, the program crashes on exit when I try to.

I have verified that it gets to the line where it sets it to NULL and that is the cause of the crash.

I've tried the following:

```
val = NULL;

val = 0;

val = "";
```

Those all cause a crash, however if I used:

```
val = new Char[1];
val = "o";
```

it didn't crash.

Is there something that I'm not doing?

Update:

Here is a quick update to my problem.

The destructor I'm using is:

```
~LField() { 
    if (val)
      delete[] val;
}
```

If I take out:

```
if (val)
  delete[] val;
```

then the program doesn't crash on exit with:

```
val = "";
```

Here is some more code as requested:

```
LField(int rowNumVal, int colNumVal, int widthVal, const char *valVal = "", bool canEditVal = true) { 
    if(strlen(valVal) > 0) {            
      //doesn't jump in here since valVal is empty
    }
    else {
      val = ""; // this is where I'm trying to set a NULL value
    }
}

LField(const LField &clone) { 
  if (val)
    delete[] val;

  val = new char[strlen(clone.val)]; 
  strcpy(val, clone.val);
  rowNum = clone.rowNum;
  colNum = clone.colNum;
  width = clone.width;
  canEdit = clone.canEdit;
  index = clone.index;
}

LField& operator=(const LField &lfieldobj) {
    if (this != &lfieldobj) {
    if (val)
       delete[] val;

    val = new char[strlen(lfieldobj.val)];
    strcpy(val, lfieldobj.val);
    rowNum = lfieldobj.rowNum;
    colNum = lfieldobj.colNum;
    width = lfieldobj.width;
    canEdit = lfieldobj.canEdit;
    index = lfieldobj.index;
   }

   return *this;
}
```

Modified:

```
LField(int rowNumVal, int colNumVal, int widthVal, const char *valVal = NULL, bool canEditVal = true) { 
    if(valVal != NULL) {            

    }
    else {
      val = NULL; 
    }
}

LField(const LField &clone) { 
  delete[] val;
  if (clone.val != NULL) {
     val = new char[strlen(clone.val) + 1]; 
     strcpy(val, clone.val);
  }
  else
    val = NULL;
  rowNum = clone.rowNum;
  colNum = clone.colNum;
  width = clone.width;
  canEdit = clone.canEdit;
  index = clone.index;
}

LField& operator=(const LField &lfieldobj) {
    if (this != &lfieldobj) {
       delete[] val;
    if (lfieldobj.val != NULL) {                
       val = new char[strlen(lfieldobj.val) + 1];
       strcpy(val, lfieldobj.val);
    }
    else
       val = NULL;
    rowNum = lfieldobj.rowNum;
    colNum = lfieldobj.colNum;
    width = lfieldobj.width;
    canEdit = lfieldobj.canEdit;
    index = lfieldobj.index;
   }

   return *this;
}

~LField() { 
      delete[] val;
}
```

I've updated the code.  Now val is either allocated memory with new[] or it is NULL, so there shouldn't be a problem with delete[].  However, it still crashes on exit.

Comment: Show us the entire class, or at least the constructor, destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Yes, throw in more code. It's hard to see anything without.

Comment: sharptooth answered the question well, so I'll just add one further comment here.  You don't need to do the not-null check before calling `delete[]`; the `delete` operator does a null check for you and does nothing if the pointer is null.

Comment: What does the "modified" constructor set the `val` to when `valVal` is not null?

Comment: You STILL have `if (val) delete[] val` in the copy constructor. Remove it. Completely. Please!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the copy constructor you try to `delete[]` an uninitialized pointer:

```
LField(const LField &clone) { 
  //good code here, then...
  if (val) //<+ some random address here
    delete[] val;//<-undefined behavior
}
```

just don't do that, skip the whole construct. The copy constructor is invoked on an unitilialized object, there're no resources to "free" yet.

Also you try to `delete[]` a string literal, that's undefined behavior. Try the following change:

```
LField(int rowNumVal, int colNumVal, int widthVal, const char *valVal = "", bool canEditVal = true) { 
    if(strlen(valVal) > 0) {            
      //doesn't jump in here since valVal is empty
    }
    else {
      val = new char[1];
      *val = 0;
    }
}
```

also the following is a buffer overrun:

```
val = new char[strlen(whatever)];  <-forgot to +1 for the null terminator
strcpy(val, whatever);
```

also checking for a null pointer before `delete[]` is unnecessary - `delete[]` on a null pointer is legal and has no effect.

Comment: Better still, change the type of `val` to `std::string` and let it manage memory for you.

Comment: I wish I could use string, it's part of the assignment to use characters.  

Thanks for pointing out I need the +1.

Sharptooth, your solution didn't work, but doing
val = new char[1];
val = "";
did work, do you think that would be and acceptable solution?

Comment: I agree with Mike, making the above code change will fix the problem but a crash can still be caused easily. Just make two instances of `LField` in which `valVal` is specified as a string literal in at least the first instance. Now try assigning the second instance to the first; the OP's code will try to `delete[]` the string literal.

Comment: @Marcin In the future, when posting homework questions, please use the homework tag.

Comment: @Marcin `val = new char[1]; val = "";` is nothing but what you already have, plus a memory leak. Remember, for C-style strings (as opposed to `std::string` objects), the `=` operator assigns the *pointer* to point to a new place. It does not copy one string value into another.

Comment: @Marcin: Your copy constructor had undefined behavior - I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm going with this solution.  Thanks sharptooth and everyone else that posted here, you were all a HUGE help.

Will do Tyler.

Answer (score 4):

Oh dear, where to start??

a:

```
LField(const LField &clone) { 
  if (val)
    delete[] val;
```

This is daft, as val is undefined. You will be calling delete[] on random memory.

b:

```
  val = new char[strlen(clone.val)]; 
  strcpy(val, clone.val);
```

c-type Strings need a null terminator. You need to new[] and additional byte.

Comment: A bit arrogant of a response, yes?

Answer (score 3):

Probably somewhere in your code you are trying to access(dereference) `val` which still refers to `NULL`.

Make sure no where in your code you are doing this

```
  val=NULL; //in the constructor

  //somewhere in your code      
  char ch= *val; //This would be Undefined Behavior
```

---

## EDIT

You are calling `delete[]` on `val` whose value is `""`(string literal), that is undefined behavior.

Some examples of UB

```
 1)
   char *p="hello";
  delete p; //UB
  delete []p; //UB

 2)
  char *p==new char[20]("Hello");
  delete p; //UB
  delete []p; //fine

 3) 
  char *p=new char('a');
  delete []p; //UB
  delete p; //fine
```

Comment: This was the first thing I checked, I'm not accessing it anywhere like that.

Comment: Calling `delete[]` on something that hasn't been allocated using `new[]` also invokes UB.

Comment: That's why I was trying to set the initial value to NULL, then in the destructor checking "if (val)" to make sure it isn't NULL, then de-allocating the memory.

Comment: @Marcin First of all, it's perfectly legal to `delete` something that is `NULL` (it's a no-op), so the check is superfluous. Secondly, the string literal `""` is also "something that isn't allocated with new", which is why your program is crashing; see sharptooth's answer.

Comment: Why a downvote? My answer before the edits corresponded to OP's question before the edits.

Comment: The edit is true, but he shouldn't be calling `delete` at all when `val == 0`.

Comment: @T.E.D. Why not? There's absolutely nothing wrong with doing that.

Comment: @Tyler McHenry: It wasn't a coding suggestion, but my reading of his code. There's an if-check around it in his desctuctor that ensures that. Replace "shouldn't" with "isn't".

Answer (score 2):

Calling

```
delete[] NULL;
delete[] 0;
```

is ok, you don't even need the null-check.
But calling

```
delete[] "whatever";
```

is not OK since this char* wasn't allocated with new[].

Note that calling string function like strlen() like it is done in your constructor is illegal in a null reference.

You access val in your constructor before it is assigned the first time. This can also cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Prasoon Saurav. The code you showed looks good, so the problem is somewhere else.

Try this:

1. Change it back to `val = 0;`
2. Remove **all** your code except the constructor, the destructor, and a declaration of an object of that class. Comment out *everything* else. I'd wager good repuation that it won't crash.
3. Slowly uncomment your other code and retry the program. When it crashes again, you've found the culprit.